# Найти самую большую дату, исключив несколько условий

Tags: excel

Есть две таблицы, в первой есть типы от 1 до 5, а во второй указан тип и дата, надо в клетку с максимальной датой вывести, дату исключив например тип 4 и 2

[image: таблицы]

В данном примере самая большая дата 05.10.2022, но нам надо исключить тип 4, следовательно так-же и с тип 2 где дата 01.10.2022, а значит самая большая дата будет 30.09.2022 у типа 3

Comment: Вы пытались сами решить задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1** Можно использовать [формулу массива](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) (Excel 2007+):

```
=МАКС($D$6:$D$13*($C$6:$C$13<>"ТИП 2")*($C$6:$C$13<>"ТИП 4"))
```

*(вводить Ctrl+Shift+Enter, признак формулы массива - она после ввода отображается в фигурных скобках):*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Константы "ТИП ..." можно заменить ссылками на соотв. ячейки

**Вариант 2** Функция [`МАКСЕСЛИ()`](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883?ns=excel&version=19&syslcid=1049&uilcid=1049&appver=zxl190&helpid=xlmain11.chm60651&ui=ru-ru&rs=ru-ru&ad=ru)(Excel 2019+):

```
=МАКСЕСЛИ($D$6:$D$13;$C$6:$C$13;"<>" & $A$6;$C$6:$C$13;"<>" & $A$8)
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В свободный столбец формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(тип={2;4});;дата)
```

где `тип` - ссылка на ячейку столбца с типами; `дата` - ссылка на ячейку столбца с датами; `{2;4}` - перечень исключаемых типов.

Формула выведет в отдельный столбец все даты нужных типов. Дальше просто:

```
=МАКС(доп_столбец)
```

---

Без доп. столбца, для любого количества исключаемых значений (формула массива, вводится одновременным нажатием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*, после ввода должна обрамиться фигурными скобками):

```
=МАКС(D2:D99*ЕНД(ПОИСКПОЗ(C2:C99;F1:F9;)))
```

здесь `C2:C99` - даты; `D2:D99` - типы; `F1:F9` - перечень исключаемых типов

Если исключений несколько, диапазон `F1:F9` можно заменить массивом констант
`{"ТИП 2";"ТИП 4"}`

Comment: Попробовал как вы написали, и не вышло, она все равно создает дополнительный столбец, где выводит все даты =ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(C2:C9={2;4});;D2:D9) я пробывал еще и такой вариант =ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(C2:C9={"ТИП 4";"ТИП 2"});;D2:D9), по разному написать, ссылку на ячейку она в тип={...} не дает вставить, а другие варианты просто выводят все даты.

Comment: Читайте внимательно: `тип` и `дата` - **ссылка на ячейку** (одну, в текущей строке), `{2;4}` - перечень с Вашими названиями типов. Ввести формулу в одну ячейку, ячейку протянуть (копировать) по строкам.

Comment: В таком случае этот вариант предполагает, обязательного создания дополнительного столбца, а мне нужно без дополнительных созданных столбцов, и да я понимаю что этот дополнительный столбец можно спрятать, но все же мне такое не подходит.

Comment: "Массивную" не предлагал, т.к. считал, что с простой вариант легче понять и применить. Не проблема, дополнил ответ